# Upload files to Azure BLOB storage - Parallel.Foreach is slower than Foreach

Tags: azure, azure-storage, task-parallel-library, azure-blob-storage, parallel.foreach

I have the following code for uploading a folder form **local storage** to blob storage, Including the folder name itself in the blob's name ( The code is based on some methods found here http://blog.smarx.com/posts/pivot-odata-and-windows-azure-visual-netflix-browsing ) :

```cs
public static void UploadBlobDir(CloudBlobContainer container, string dirPath)
        {
            string dirName = new Uri(dirPath).Segments.Last();

            Parallel.ForEach(enumerateDirectoryRecursive(dirPath), file =>
                {
                    string blobName = Path.Combine(dirName, Path.GetFullPath(file)).Substring(dirPath.Length - dirName.Length);
                    container.GetBlobReference(blobName).UploadFile(file);
                });
        }
```

and :

```cs
private static IEnumerable<string> enumerateDirectoryRecursive(string root)
        {
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(root))
                yield return file;
            foreach (var subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(root))
                foreach (var file in enumerateDirectoryRecursive(subdir))
                    yield return file;
        }
```

This code works and uploads the folder as intended but it takes an awful lot of time to complete - It takes **20 seconds to upload**  25 files, 40KB~ each. So I tired to replace the parallel loop with a regular one like so :

```cs
foreach (var file in enumerateDirectoryRecursive(i_DirPath))
            {
                string blobName = Path.Combine(dirName, Path.GetFullPath(file)).Substring(i_DirPath.Length - dirName.Length);
                container.GetBlobReference(blobName).UploadFile(file);
            }
```

Now the uploading completes instantly (**3 Seconds** Approx.).

It's also important to note that I am working against the **storage emulator** for development.
The Parallel.Forech should obviously be faster. Does this difference comes form the storage emulator limitations (And when going live, Parallel would be faster) or is it something else I might be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, the storage emulator tells you **strictly nothing** about the performance you should expect (or not) from the actual Azure Storage. The emulator is typically extremely slow.

Then `Parallel.Foreach` will only be faster if your transfer happen to be **latency-bound** rather than I/O bound. Then, please note that `Parallel.Foreach` will only use your number of CPU as the default parallelization degree. For latency-bound processes, you should typically have much more threads than that, typically 4 to 8 threads per CPU (YMMV).

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what do you mean by I/O bound and latency-bound, and what case does my code belongs to ? (Just a reminder, I am uploading from local storage, in case it matters)

Comment: You can get maximum parallelization by using asynchronous transfers.

Comment: @OliverBock Can you be more specific ? Do you mean using the Parallel.Foreach and inside it call to what async api ?

Comment: @YaronLevi, call CloudBlob.BeginUploadFromStream() in a normal for loop.  It will take care of starting and running the upload asynchronously and will call you back (from another thread) when done.